# Unable to search for specific term via Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It seems Facebook is preventing search of a specific term.

As part of a site we are launching, had planned to query Facebook for the term `#bestsummerever`.

So the request to Graph API using an app access token for public data is the form:

```
/search/?q=%23bestsummerever
```

This now gives me the following error:

```
OAuthException
An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
```

The error is new sometime between last week and this week.

I can query other "hashtags" with no issue, all of the following work:

```
/search/?q=%23bestsummereve
/search/?q=%23bestsummereverr
/search/?q=%23bestsummer
```

So it seems like I am strictly being prevented from querying `#bestsummerever`.  This seems to be consistent regardless of what app I make the request with.

There does not seem to be any documented reason for this issue.

Can be reproduced using any app access token on the [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).  Really hoping this is some kind of small oversight on my part, but seems more like Facebook has some kind of restriction on that specific term.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Facebook requires that you provide an User Access Token if you search for obejcts other than places and pages (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search).

Apparently there IS some strange behaviour with your desired hashtag:

```
GET /search?q=%23selfie&type=post
```

works fine, whereas

```
GET /search?q=%23bestsummerever&type=post
```

produces an error. But

```
GET /search?q=bestsummerever&type=post
```

works for me. Strange, but maybe you can go on without the hashtag for now.

Comment: No hashtag is my plan for now.  Thanks for the input.  I do ask that you at least edit your answer, as Facebook most certainly does **not** require a user access token for the search endpoint.  Please re-read the documentation in the link you attached.  `All Graph API search queries require an access token included in the request. The type of access token you need depends on the type of search you're executing.

Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.`

Comment: It's exactly as I wrote, Page and Place require an App Access Token, and I quote FB: "Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token. All other endpoints require a user access token". So I don't see why I should edit my answer!

Comment: It's not constructive or related to my issue, and the way you state it makes it seem like it solves a problem.  You're fine to leave it- the rest of your answer was constructive.

Comment: It is/was constructive, because you did not specify a search type in your question. And you were saying that you're using an App Access Token. I referenced the docs to make you aware that there's a potential problem with the Access Tokens. And if you don't mind I'd like to reply if you're only quoting half of the according docs and say I'm not correct...